# Check if div contains any overflowing inline-block spans

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to detect if there are any spans in a container that are overflowing and hidden.

```
<div class="container">
    <span>one</span><span>two</span><span>three</span><span>four</span><span>five</span><span>six</span><span>seven</span><span>eight</span>
</div>
```

.

```
.container {
    width: 150px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
span {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 6px; 
}
```

The only way I could think of doing this is by selecting the last span element, and determining whether it's within the container.

[my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mb4vnyk/)

Comment: Do you only want to detect if there are overflowing elements? Or which ones are overflowing? What do you want to do based on this information?

Comment: I need to also detect which elements are overflowing.

Comment: Then I would say what you suggested in your post is the way to go. Loop backwards over the elements, breaking when the element is within the wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
// container 1 should be 'yes'
var cont = document.getElementById("container");
if (cont.scrollWidth > cont.offsetWidth) {
  alert("yes");
} else {
  alert("no");
}
// container 2 should be 'no'
var cont1 = document.getElementById("container1");
if (cont1.scrollWidth > cont1.offsetWidth) {
  alert("yes");
} else {
  alert("no");
}
```

```css
.container,
.container2 {
  margin: 25px;
  background: lightgrey;
  width: 150px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
span {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" id="container">
  <span>one</span><span>two</span><span>three</span><span>four</span><span>five</span><span>six</span><span>seven</span><span>eight</span>
</div>

<div class="container2" id="container1">
  <span>one</span><span>two</span><span>three</span>
</div>
```

I tried the following JS fiddle.  It gives me the correct answer. I added an ID to each element for simplicity.

http://jsfiddle.net/caqL13pq/1/

```
// container 1 should be 'yes'
var cont=document.getElementById("container");
if(cont.scrollWidth>cont.offsetWidth){
    alert("yes");
}else{
    alert("no");
}
// container 2 should be 'no'
var cont1=document.getElementById("container1");
if(cont1.scrollWidth>cont1.offsetWidth){
    alert("yes");
}else{
    alert("no");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($(".container").get(0).scrollWidth > $(".container").outerWidth())
{
    alert("Yes");
}
else
{
    alert("No");
}

if($(".container2").get(0).scrollWidth > $(".container2").outerWidth())
{
    alert("Yes");
}
else
{
    alert("No");
}
```

**[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mb4vnyk/1/)**